# normalize usage data

Tags: correlation, normalization

I'm looking at identifying trends within my data, particularly wondering if usage of my app on new sign ups is increasing over a week to week basis.  As we are constantly improving our product, I'd love to be able to identify a correlation between app usage & new feature releases.

The data I have is split into weekly cohorts.  Each week I have the number of new sign ups, and how many of those accounts are still active (e.g. users are logging into the system).

Let's say I have the following data

Week 1 - 10 new trials, 3 accounts active

Week 2 - 15 new trials, 5 accounts active

week 3 - 4 new trials, 3 accounts active

week 4 - 20 new trials, 12 accounts active

week 5 - 17 new trials, 9 accounts active

In my current approach of analysis, week 3 looks amazing because 75% of accounts are still active ... In reality though, the number of new trials is extremely small compared to other weeks.  As a result, I don't feel like I'm accurately comparing apples to apples in a week to week comparison.

Is there a way I can normalize the weekly data so that I am performing accurate analysis - or is percentage based really the best way to look at this data?

I am pretty new to this, so any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! Consider modeling your activity with a Beta random variable.

Comment: @Emre Thanks - can you point to any tutorials on how to use beta random variables for a dummy.  I'm struggling to understand how i'd apply this to my problem.

Comment: I hope [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution) helps. You haven't mentioned how you are modeling the features though; an binary variable to indicate whether a feature was introduced that week?

Comment: I literally have no idea what I am doing, hence the ask for tutorials.  I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Maybe you need to step back and get a book on statistics? Larry Wasserman's _All of Statistics_ isn't bad.

Comment: Thanks Emre ... Going to jump into a few books and also look at some data science courses to get my head wrapped around this.  I thought maybe there was an established algorithm to solving this stuff, but the more I look into it, the more I realize there is not one right answer.

Answer (score 1):

With this low number of sign ups I doubt you can profit from advanced statistics at this stage. Just chart your numbers in excel along the timeline and judge visually.

Comment: What if signups were in the 100's?  The above data was dummy data.

Comment: If you can have the sign ups broken down per day you could try using CausalImpact from Google or Probablistic Programming  https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers to see what the effect is.

Answer (score 1):

Try Normalizing the trails and active accounts data with a mean or median.  The resulting statistics will show week 3 as negative values which can be interpreted as a comparison to all the data.  See the Excel graphs below.

[image: mean normal]
[image: mean median combo]

As opposed to the data that has not been normalized.
[image]